# Servicestack client outside of .NET framework, implementation?

Tags: android, asp.net, rest, servicestack

I plan on consuming the REST services provided by ServiceStack outside of .NET. I plan to writing clients for java and obj-c. This should be easy since it is a REST service, however in the documentation it seems to suggest otherwise:

> But ServiceStack includes two clients which are optimized for ServiceStack in aspects like exception handling etc.

How would I go about implementing a ServiceStack client with Android? Just follow normal REST consumption procedures? Should I worry about any exception handling issues?

Also, would authentication be an issue (I'll be using BasicAuthentication)?

Comment: How does that quote imply you can't use it with Android?  If it's REST then by definition you can.

Comment: It just came across as suggesting that it wasn't 100% RESTful. And I was trying to make sure that this isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ServiceStack web services provide pure HTTP/REST APIs which are essentially just serialized POCO DTOs over the wire. You control the entire HTTP output as ServiceStack doesn't add any additional cruft around your serialized payloads.

#### Expects Pure Serialized DTOs

The *opinionated* nature comes from the ServiceClients assuming that the services are just returning pure serialized DTOs (i.e. without additional cruft) which it simply deserializes as-is into the specified response type. The ServiceClients are unique in that they give you a strong-typed end-to-end API without any code-gen since you're able to re-use the POCO DTOs you defined your web services with.

#### Fallback to pre-defined routes

The APIs that don't speicfy a `relativeOrAbsoluteUri` in the API like the [Send<TResponse>(dto)](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/ServiceClientBase.cs#L298) will by default use the [pre-defined routes](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#predefinedroutes) automatically provided by ServiceStack allowing you to call web services without needing to specify any Custom routes for them. You can of-course opt to use your custom routes instead by sticking to the [IRestClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Service/IRestClient.cs) and [IRestClientAsync](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Service/IRestClientAsync.cs) APIs which allow you to specify the url to use.

#### Automatic Error Handling

The C# ServiceStack ServiceClients are *optimized* in that by convention ServiceStack web services will serialize structured error responses in a **ResponseStatus** property on your Response DTO (only if it has one). All the service clients do is just de-serialize the error response into a typed C# WebServiceException which gives your C# clients strong-typed access to structured errors as explained in detail in the [Validation wikipage](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Validation).

Basically the ResponseStatus property is just a convention (not some anti-REST magic) and you still control what HttpStatus Code and Description gets returned. It's simply another pure DTO property that all REST clients have equal access to - here's a [simple JavaScript ss-validation.js](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/NuGet/ServiceStack.Host.Mvc/content/Content/js/ss-validation.js#L41) routine that extracts the responseStatus metadata and injects the errors onto a Twitter Bootstrap HTML Form.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. That answers my question perfectly.